# Different ways to order 3 scoops of ice cream and order them depending on cone or bowl and other conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

[image]

I was just wondering if someone can let me know if my solutions are correct and/or if I am approaching the problems the correct way.

a)If the 3 scoops of ice cream are being placed in a bowl....
I decided to approach this with multichoosing so I had 3 multichoose 31 which is the equivalent of 31 stars and 2 bars.

Therefore I had 33C31 which I evaluated to 528

b)now for the 3 scoops of ice cream are being placed in a cone where the order of the ice cream in the cone matters I was thinking 31x31x31x3. Since for each of the scoops there are 31 flavors or options and then times 3 to evaluate the different ordering of the 3 scoops chosen.

However I've come to realize can't I order 3 scoops of different ice cream 6 ways?Also what if two flavors are repeated then ordering becomes more technical. Should this question also be approached with multi choosing. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the cone problem, how many ways can you choose the bottom scoop? middle scoop? top scoop?

Comment: each scoop can be chosen 31 different ways since there are 31 flavors, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: so I don't need the times 6 portion to account for different arrangements? like having chocolate vanilla strawberry would be different then strawberry chocolate vanilla according to this question

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: so how would you go about accounting for that piece. Multiplying by what? I feel like there is no set number to multiply by depending if no flavors are repeated, 2 flavors are repeated or 1 flavor is repeated. Do I need to break this problem up into cases next?

Comment: May I start a chat to ask you another combinatorial question if you don't mind? Just on how to get a problem set up?

Comment: Sure.  What is your question?

Comment: regarding an algebraic expansion. How do I set up a chat?

Comment: It looks like you should go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and create a new room.  Here is the faq page: https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq.

Comment: I created a room called algebraic expansion. Thank you

Comment: Are you writing your question in the chat room?  I just see a message telling me that the page is "Loading Algebraic Expansion Just a Second ..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74151/discussion-between-lil-and-n-f-taussig).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many ways are there to have $3$ scoops of ice cream placed in a bowl?

Your answer is correct.

> How many ways are there to have $3$ scoops of ice cream placed on a cone?

Each possible cone can be viewed as a choice of bottom, middle, and top scoops.  There are $31$ choices for each level of cone, so there are $31^3$ possible ways to order a $3$-scoop cone.

Comment: since I'm literally choosing my scoop each time it already counts all the cases where they are being ordered differently like chocolate vanilla strawberry and strawberry vanilla chocolate. I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: sorry one more thing. Lets pretend flavors weren't allowed to be repeated in both cases- the cone and the bowl would the solution to both be 31x30x29. I'm wondering how the solutions to the cone and bowl would be different in that case.

Comment: The number of cones would be $31 \cdot 30 \cdot 29$.  However, the number of $3$-scoop bowls would be $\binom{31}{3}$ since we do not care about the order of the flavors in the bowl.

Comment: got it permutation vs combination. Perfect! Thank you again for all your help!